# Не могу вызвать функцию из модуля

Tags: javascript

1. файлы sayHi.js и main.js находятся в одной папке
2. файл sayHi.js export функцию
3. файл main.js функцию import
4. В чем ошибка ?

```js
//  sayHi.js
export function sayHi(user) {
  alert(`Hello, ${user}!`);
}
```

```js
//  main.js
import {sayHi} from './sayHi.js';

alert(sayHi); // function...
sayHi('John'); // Hello, John!
```

Comment: где пробуешь и как:?

Comment: файл main.js перетаскиваю в браузер

Comment: это так на работает

Comment: @Grundy не работает ?

Comment: да, в браузере модули своеобразно поддерживаются

Comment: @Grundy у меня в консоли выведено from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: про это тоже было, в настройках браузера можно порпробовать найти галочки

Comment: лучше всего конечно локальный сервер запустить

Comment: @Grundy встроенная в js система модулей уже можно использовать в боевых проектах ?

Comment: смотря что считать боевым проектом

Comment: @Grundy использовать в лендинге или интернет-магазин ?

Comment: модули поддерживаются не по всех браузерах, поэтому нужно оценить, достаточен ли процент поддерживающих, чтобы не обращать внимания на остальных

Comment: @Grundy ок спасибо что ответили на вопросы, удачи